# How to import a csv into a remote Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, csv, amazon-ec2, remote-access, amazon-rds

I have a dump from a database in a csv format ('|' character as the delimiter), and I want to import that into a remote Oracle database. I am using AWS and the csv is on an EC2 instance running amazon linux, and the remote Oracle database is an RDS instance. This is the first time I'm touching an Oracle database.

I expected this to be fairly simple, but trying to find info I kind of got lost. Some people say to use SQL*Loader, but I can't manage to even install that thing. Other's say that SQL*Loader is not supposed to even be installed on something that isn't the actual database server. So far I've only managed to install sqlplus and connect to the database, but no importing so far.

Basically I'm looking for an equivalent of \COPY in psql, but for Oracle. And how on earth would I use it in this context.

Comment: SQL\*Loader is a client program; you can use it with the client software installation (but not instant client - it may be hackable but you need the full client really). I think SQL Developer lets you import from CSV but I haven't used that functionality. If AWS/RDS lets you have access to a directory on the server - which it might do for impdp - then an external table is useful. Depends what you're allowed to do and what software you can install.

Comment: Interesting, every time I googled something like "install Oracle tools" I was directed towards the instant client and didn't even know there is a "full client" out there.

Comment: [Client is second from the bottom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-linux-download-2240591.html). Instant client is much simpler to install and use, but is limited; it doesn't have loader, export/import, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SQL*Loader and only need to import CSV as a one time task, I would recommend using **SQL Developer**. If you want an automated process, SQL*Loader would probably be your best bet.

Here are some links (note that an Excel import and a CSV import are nearly identical):

- [How to move csv file into oracle database using sql developer? [closed]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51248/how-to-move-csv-file-into-oracle-database-using-sql-developer)
- [How to Import from Excel to a New Oracle Table with SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/how-to-import-from-excel-to-a-new-oracle-table-with-sql-developer/)
- [How to Import from Excel to Oracle with SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/)

Comment: I might be misinterpreting, but this looks like a GUI application and tailored towards windows. I am ssh'd into an EC2 instance and only have access to command line tools that run on linux.

Comment: Yes, SQL Developer is a GUI application (Java, also runs on Linux). In this case, I would either use SQL\*Loader or write a small BASH script to generate all INSERT-Statements and run those with SQL*Plus. As Alex Poole noted above, you might also be able to use external tables to import your CSV if you have access to a directory on the database server.